Rust IndexedDB A version change transaction is running
I'm new to Rust and I'm trying to open a connection to IndexedDB here is the full code:
use crate::items_page::items_structs::Item;
use leptos::{
    component, create_signal, event_target_value, logging, view, IntoView, SignalGet, SignalSet,
};

use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;
use wasm_bindgen::JsCast;
use web_sys::{window, IdbDatabase, IdbOpenDbRequest, IdbTransactionMode, IdbVersionChangeEvent};

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub async fn open_database() -> Result<IdbDatabase, JsValue> {
    let window = window().expect("should have a Window");
    let indexed_db = window.indexed_db()?.expect("should support IndexedDB");

    let request = indexed_db.open_with_u32("my-database", 1)?;
    let (sender, receiver) = futures_channel::oneshot::channel();
    let sender = Some(sender); // Wrap sender in an Option

    logging::log!("Before on_upgrade_needed");

    let on_upgrade_needed = {
        let mut sender = sender; // Make mutable so we can take() from it
        Closure::wrap(Box::new(move |event: IdbVersionChangeEvent| {
            let db = event
                .target()
                .unwrap()
                .dyn_into::<IdbOpenDbRequest>()
                .unwrap()
                .result()
                .unwrap();
            let db = db.dyn_into::<IdbDatabase>().unwrap();

            // Create an object store if it doesn't exist
            if !db.object_store_names().contains("store") {
                db.create_object_store("store").unwrap();
            }

            // Send the database if sender is available
            if let Some(sender) = sender.take() {
                let _ = sender.send(db);
            }
        }) as Box<dyn FnMut(_)>)
    };

    logging::log!("After on_upgrade_needed");

    request.set_onupgradeneeded(Some(on_upgrade_needed.as_ref().unchecked_ref()));
    on_upgrade_needed.forget();

    logging::log!("After on_upgrade_needed.forget();");

    receiver
        .await
        .map_err(|_| JsValue::from_str("Database open failed"))
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub async fn add_data(db: &IdbDatabase, key: &str, value: &JsValue) -> Result<(), JsValue> {
    logging::log!("Adding data to IndexedDB");

    // Start a readwrite transaction
    let tx = db
        .transaction_with_str_and_mode("store", IdbTransactionMode::Readwrite)
        .expect("Error on tx");
    let store = tx.object_store("store").expect("Error on store");

    // Add data to the store
    store.add_with_key(value, &JsValue::from_str(key))?;
    Ok(())
}

#[component]
pub fn ItemsPage() -> impl IntoView {
    let (product_name, set_product_name) = create_signal(String::new());
    let (product_price, set_product_price) = create_signal(String::new());

    let onSubmit = move || {
        wasm_bindgen_futures::spawn_local(async move {
            let db: IdbDatabase = open_database().await.unwrap();
            logging::log!("Got the db {:?}", db);

            add_data(
                &db,
                &product_name.get(),
                &JsValue::from_str(&product_price.get()),
            )
            .await
            .unwrap();
            // logging::log!("{}, {}", name, rice);
        })
    };

    let employee = move || {};

    view! {
        <input class="block" type="text" placeholder="Item name here" value={product_name} on:input=move |ev| {set_product_name.set(event_target_value(&ev))}/>
        <input class="block" type="text" placeholder="Item price here" value={product_price} on:input=move |ev| {set_product_price.set(event_target_value(&ev))}/>

        <button class="block" on:click=move |_| {onSubmit()}>Add item to IndexedDB</button>

         <button on:click=move |_| {employee()}>Get employee</button>
    }
}

And I'm getting this error:

Error on tx: JsValue(InvalidStateError: Failed to execute
'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': A version change transaction is
running.

